# Data Visualization by use of json and javascript

Tags: javascript, json, raphael, visualization, d3.js

Assume I had a json data like this :

```
{
  "node1": {
     id: "1", 
     name: "node1", 
     type: "A", 
     children: [
      {
       id: "11", 
       name: "node11", 
       children: [
        {
         id: "node111", 
         name: "node111", 
         leaf: true
        },
        {
         id: "node112", 
         name: "node112", 
         leaf: true
        }
       ]
      }
    ]},
"node2": {
   id: "12", 
   name: "node12", 
   children: [
    {
     id: "node121", 
     name: "node121", 
     leaf: true
    } 
  ]
}
```

}

I want to show such a data in graphical tree by use of js framework. I google it and found some good libraries like raphael, d3 ... but all of them can not read the json data and create the relational path from one node to another. I need a smart library which should recognize the parent and child relation of my data and add line between them. any idea for this? thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the JSON data? This is an object literal. Your problem does not seem to be with JSON. Also, if library X does not understand your format, you have to convert it to a format it understands.

Comment: Event handling on elements is important too.

Comment: Also: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/142802).

Comment: sorry, I updated my post. by the way i know sof is not a recommendation engine but this is my question from all experts here, i mean using of their experience to find the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is tree stuctured. The Infovis library seems do visualize that good: http://thejit.org/demos/

But as @Felix Kling says, you might have to restructure your data to match the X library.

Comment: jit's output is only an image, event handling is not implemented. I search for sth like raphael but clever than that.